# Double Decoding return Empty File

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I'm trying to decode a `csv` file from `FORM` on my Django Page.
I'm not sure if users send the csv file as `UTF-8` or `shift_jis_2004`. I'm trying to check this in `Exception` but when I try to `decode` th second time file is decoded but empty, why?

```py
exception = None
csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file"]

try:
    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')

except UnicodeError:
    exception = UnicodeError

if exception == UnicodeError:
    try:
        data_set = csv_file.read().decode('shift_jis_2004') # This read the file but returns empty var
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Cant Decode this')
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.CONTEXT)
```

Encoding type is not wrong because when I try the first `decode` and insert there `'shift_jis_2004'` instead of that `'utf-8'` it works. But when I'm doing the same in `try` it decode the data (Don't throw an `except`) but the variable is empty.

Even if I do something like this

```
csv_file_second = request.FILES["csv_file"]
```

And try to decode this in `Try` it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-seekable file-like objects are only readable once; `request.FILES["csv_file"]` returns a file-like object (it doesn't matter if you look it up twice, it's the same object), and the first `read()` consumes it, leaving nothing for the second `read()` to get. Separate reading from decoding, so you only `read()` once, and try to `decode` it multiple ways if needed:

```
exception = None
csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file"]

csv_data = csv_file.read()

try:
    data_set = csv_data.decode('utf-8')

except UnicodeError:
    exception = UnicodeError

if exception == UnicodeError:
    try:
        data_set = csv_data.decode('shift_jis_2004')
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Cant Decode this')
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.CONTEXT)
```

You could simplify this a bit by letting the exception block handle the second `decode` instead of setting and testing a variable:

```
csv_data = request.FILES["csv_file"].read()

try:
    data_set = csv_data.decode('utf-8')    
except UnicodeError:
    try:
        data_set = csv_data.decode('shift_jis_2004')
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Cant Decode this')
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.CONTEXT)
```